# Laughing At The Wrong Time

Tags: logical-deduction, alphametic

Uh...
Every letter corresponds to a different digit and 0 cannot be a leading digit.
Find $HA+UH$ if $$\begin{array}{cccc}
  & H & A \\
+ & H & A \\
+ & H & A \\
+ & H & A \\
\hline
  & U & H \\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Uh, 4 Hs add up to a single digit so H is 1 or 2. But four As add up to something with H as the low digit so H is not 1 (must be even). So H is 2. Then the only thing A could be is 3 or 8. If it were 8 then 4x8=32 and we carry 3. 4x2+3 = 11, more than a single digit. So A must be 3. 4x3=12 so we carry one to the tens column. U = 4x2+1 = 9. So HA + UH = 23 + 92 = 115. Ha ha.

Comment: I got the same answer, but don't get how it connects to "laughing" in the title, and why you wrote haha at the end

Comment: @nuggethead uh, the addends are HA (laughing) and the sum is UH (i guess this indicates it's the wrong time to laugh) ha ha.

Comment: But does the sum at the end have any significance?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: But according to Wikipedia: 115 is also a heptagonal pyramidal number. The 115th Woodall number,

$2^{115}-1=4\;776\;913\;109\;852\;041\;418\;248\;056\;622\;882\;488\;319$,
is a prime number.